# How can i get Team City builds to show up in TFS's build explorer

Tags: tfs, teamcity, coded-ui-tests, mtm

So here's the setup we have right now

1) We use TFS2013 for our code repository

2) We use TeamCity to do our builds

3) we have our tests created in CodedUI

From what I've read online is that for the CodedUI tests to run automatically, they need a build to reference.  However, since we are using Team City to do the builds, our Build Explorer in TFS is empty.  Switching off of Team City for builds is a no, so I'm trying to find a way to have the builds appear in the Build Explorer so I can have the automated tests run via MTM.

TL;DR: I need to get the Team City builds to appear in the TFS Build Explorer.

I saw this question, but it was for 2010, so I'm hoping it's changed since [How do I make a TeamCity build appear in the TFS Build Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889410/how-do-i-make-a-teamcity-build-appear-in-the-tfs-build-explorer/10968843#10968843)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a TeamCity build appear in the TFS Build Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889410/how-do-i-make-a-teamcity-build-appear-in-the-tfs-build-explorer)

Comment: that question was for TFS 2010 and said it couldn't do so.  Hence I specified I was asking for TFS 2013

Comment: Turns out to be the same answer for all versions of TFS, and likely will remain so - no way to do it. You should look to see if you can kick off a Team City build from a TFS build definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using the API. You could use the following blog post as a starting point to create an app that records in TFS the results from your TeamCity build. Then you could run your app as part of your TeamCity build.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/02/23/creating-fake-builds-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx

Update: There are however downsides. Some capabilities of ALM are only available if the build is done in TFS. You loose Test Impact Analysis, relationships between builds and Work Items, identification of Verifiable Bug fixes, roll up for release management of release contents.

TF Build is more than just orchestrating a compilation, it is the glue that knits your ALM strategy together and you will not be able to amortize the realm value in TFS without builds in TF Build or a whole lot of custom work.

Comment: Though using the same api, it is technically possible to reach feature parity on most of these gaps. But it requires a bunch of custom tasks / actions to create the build, associate the work items and that once you have that setup you can run the standard tools and point them to the 'fake' build uri.

Comment: Heh, you only lose all the important stuff.  I wouldn't suggest customers actually do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's not possible.   Team Explorer is designed to show you Team Builds.